# Keyboard shortcuts using Ctrl don't work sometimes

Tags: shortcut-keys

Running Ubuntu 16.04.
Very often, keyboard shortcuts do not work. Here are some examples:

1. From anywhere, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> should open Terminal; it does nothing
2. From Firefox, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> should copy the selected text; it does not
3. In Thunderbird, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> should paste the text; it does not
4. In Firefox, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> should open Terminal; instead, it opens the Tools menu
5. From anywhere, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> should trigger Keepass2 autotype; it does nothing

Some additional observations:

- It appears that combinations using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are the problem; combinations using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Something (without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) seem to work OK
- I never used to have this problem - all keyboard shortcuts worked OK. So...what changed? Unfortunately, I cannot pinpoint the change.
- I checked other messages here about similar problems. None of solutions there seem pertinent, insofar as I have not upgraded from an earlier version of Ubuntu and I have not installed any of the software identified as being the source of the problem.
- LBNL, while some shortcuts have simply stopped working at all, notably the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> mentioned above, others, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> *do* work very often.

Comment: check **Ctrl** settings in `gnome-tweaks`, you had probably state a particular option there

Comment: That's not the case. If it were simply a question of a setting, then it wouldn't work sometimes but not other times.